# Loop only saves last line to csv

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to save a json page to a csv but it only stores the last row (although everything is visible on the print statement).

Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
url = 'http://mapit.mysociety.org/areas/WMC'

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

html = response.read()

data = json.loads(html)

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,['id', 'gss','name','country_name'])
    w.writeheader() 


    for entry in data.values():

        record = {
            "id": entry["id"],
            "gss": entry["codes"]["gss"],
            "name": entry["name"],
            "country_name": entry["country_name"],
        }

        print record

        w.writerow(record)
```

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards

Comment: What you posted looks like it would work. Any chance the last line is mistakenly unindented in the copy you're running?

Comment: Works exactly as is for me on 2.7.8, at least until it hits unicode errors, but that's out of the scope of the question.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for testing guys. There was an in fact an indentation issue with the last line.